# HTTP (FORM) brute force cracker freeware

Tags: windows, security, nas, http

We use a NAS in our small office which is set-up so that each person has their own private directory on it. However the password to enter the HTTP administration area has been forgotten so we're unable to add/edit further people onto it.

Rather than doing a reset of the device and possibility losing data, I thought this might be an interesting chance to run a cracker against it to recover the password.

Please note we run Windows, so no Linux software please :)

Comment: It's probably worth checking it hasn't been left on the manufacturers default password which should be available from their web site.

Comment: Good thinking - Unfortunatly I already gave that a shot and it wasn't username: admin and password: password ;)

Answer (score 1):

John the Ripper, www.insecure.org. Earned its name with hackers.

From cnet - informative pages about the programs:

http://download.cnet.com/Password-Cracker/3000-2092_4-10226556.html

http://download.cnet.com/Password-Recovery-Pro/3000-2092_4-10126332.html

From sectools.com - also provides good info, plus, I think that these are the tools that hacker mainly use:

http://sectools.org/crackers.html

Comment: Google it and search the web is not valid answers. Please provide exact links with detailed information.

Comment: @Diago Fixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [brutus](http://www.hoobie.net/brutus/), and if you want wordlists for bruteforcing, try one of [these](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2008/02/password-cracking-wordlists-and-tools-for-brute-forcing/)